# How to match multiple patterns with a regex in C++ 11

Tags: regex, c++11

Suppose there is a string named path that needs to match multiple patterns. The regular expression string is as follows:

```
std::string regexString="(/api/Attachment)|(/api/Attachment/upload)|(/api/Attachment/download)|(/api/v1/ApiTest)|(/api/v1/ApiTest/get/[^/]*/[^/]*)|(/api/v1/ApiTest/[^/]*/List)";
```

The matching code is as follows:

```
std::smatch result;
if (std::regex_match(path, result, regexString))
{
    for (size_t i = 1; i < result.size(); i++)
    {
        /// Question: Is there any better way to find the sub-match index without using a loop?
        if (!result[i].matched)
            continue;
        if (result[i].str() == path)
        {
            std::cout<<"Match a pattern with index "<<i<<std::endl;
            /// Do something with it;
            break;
        }
     }
 }
 else
 {
     std::cout<<"Match none"<<std::endl;
 }
```

The above program works, but considering a large number of patterns, the loop in it is a bit ugly and inefficient. As the comments in the code show, my question is is there a way to find the sub-match index without using loops?

Any comments would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: It isn't quite clear what your loop is doing.

Comment: After the match is successful, I want to know which one in these patterns matches, so I use a loop to find the index `i`, which I can use to perform some post-sequence jobs, such as finding the handle function based on the pattern identified by the index.

Comment: You have only one pattern.

Comment: You are right, but notice that in my question the pattern is a series of sub-patterns connecting by the "OR" operator, so what I really want to know is the index of the sub-pattern.

Comment: @eprom I think you are approaching this the wrong way.  I recommend just using a single conceptual group for all matches.

Comment: All results have the match member set to true. If you ‏only use caprure groups that can match the entire string, there will be no more than one submatch.

Comment: @n.m. Thanks for your answer. This question comes from a web application framework I wrote. I want to find a handler function registered into the framework by a path pattern. There are many path pattern and handler function pairs in the framework, Notice that the patterns may contain wildcards, so the std::map will not work. What the regex do is: path in http request--->path pattern(-->handler function).  I don't know if I describe it clearly, thank you for your attention.

Comment: Why it's very clear. It is unclear however why you think that matching one combined regex would be faster than matching each individual path pattern with a separate regex. *If* you measure your code and find that it's indeed faster that way, you can (1) turn groups in your individual path patterns into non-capturing groups (with `(?...)`) ans (2) combine the resulting path patterns with `(pat1)|...|(patN)`.

Comment: Sorry what I have said before is incorrect, there will be elements in the result with `matched` set to `false`. This is actually the only way to know which of the groups has matched. You however won't need to check `result[i].str()==path`.

Comment: Yes, the `result[i].str()==path` is unnecessary. Although your conclusion makes me a little desperate, I am very grateful!

Answer (score 1):

Try just using a single alternation which covers all variations.  In the pattern below, I also turn off capturing in the alternation.  This leaves us with fairly straightforward matching logic.  If the `smatch` result *does* have an entry, then it should be a single entry with the entire matching path.  Otherwise, it should be empty.

```
std::string regexString="/api/(?:Attachment|Attachment/upload|Attachment/download|v1/ApiTest|v1/ApiTest/get/[^/]*/[^/]*|v1/ApiTest/[^/]*/List)";
std::string s ("/api/Attachment/upload");
std::regex e (regexString);

std::smatch sm;
std::regex_match (s,sm,e);

if (sm.size() > 0) {
    std::cout << "found a matching path: " << sm[0];
}

found a matching path: /api/Attachment/upload
```

Comment: on side note: This regex can be fairly shorten. instead of repeating `Attachment|Attachment/upload|Attachment/download` it can be `Attachment|Attachment/upload|download`

Comment: @CodeManiac Yes, but remember that code has to maintained.  By keeping each subpath as a separate entry, the regex is easier to read.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks for your answer. But the sm[0] will always equle to the string `s` after matching and I still don't know which sub-path matches. Maybe you have guessed that the problem comes from a web application framework, I want to do different handle functions on different subpaths, so I want to find not only the matching result but also the subpath.

Comment: I don't get it.  You know the subpath because you have the original full input path.  Am I missing something?

Comment: There are some subpaths having wildcards in them such as `v1/ApiTest/get/[^/]*/[^/]*` or `v1/apitest/user/[^/]*/info`, so input path is not equel to the subpath.
If all subpaths don't have wildcards, I'll use std::map instead of std::regex.

Comment: That's fine, but again, if the input path does match, you should be able to just use some C++ API to extract the exact subpath.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes, the API you said is exactly what I am looking for because using a loop to check each sub-match is inefficient. But the question is what the API is.

Comment: Good question, and that would make a great new question.  This question was about regex, not string path operations.