# C++ multiple regex conditions syntax

Tags: c++, regex

In other words, is there an AND operator in c++ regex? Normally I would just use | but it doesn't work

For example I want to return only 2 and 1 digit numbers

```
string subject("This 91 - 500abc7 is a 5 test");
regex re("\\d\\d");
```

This only returns 2 digit numbers, how do I add a second condition to also match single digits "\d"

Result should be:
91 - 7 - 5

Comment: What would be the match in `1234` or `a12a`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to match multiple patterns with a regex in C++ 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54965442/how-to-match-multiple-patterns-with-a-regex-in-c-11)

Comment: mmh no, ("\\d\\d,\\d") doesn't work. neither ("\\d\\d | \\d")

Comment: What about `(?>[^\\d](\\d{1,2})[^\\d])`?

Answer (score 2):

It is not a "and" you want to have 1 OR 2 digits `(\d|\d\d)`.

but regex have notation for numbered repetition: `\d{1,2}`

Issue is that `\d{1,2}` would match `50` in `500`.

So you might add (negative) look ahead/behind:

[`(?<!\d)\d{1,2}(?!\d)`](https://regex101.com/r/m295nu/1) (1 or 2 digits not preceded and followed by another digit)

so `std::regex re(R"((?<!\d)\d{1,2}(?!\d))");`